# React Native *A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gradle-plugin'.*

Tags: react-native, gradle

```
r - reload the app
d - open developer menu
i - run on iOS
a - run on Android

info Opening the app on Android...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gradle-plugin'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\siddh\.gradle\caches\jars-9\196b729407d7fbb2907378f4b4c34b5a\kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.10.jar.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

When I ran my Application then it gives me this error;
I tried deleating android folder and configured it again,
I tried removing .gradle file


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gradle-plugin'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\siddh\.gradle\caches\jars-9\196b729407d7fbb2907378f4b4c34b5a\kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.10.jar.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s

    at makeError (C:\Users\siddh\Desktop\Business\Jicro\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\siddh\Desktop\Business\Jicro\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\siddh\Desktop\Business\Jicro\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\siddh\Desktop\Business\Jicro\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

When i ran my app then it start producing this error;

I tried removing the Android Folder and re-configured it;

I tried removing .gradle folder and re build but it gives me same error;

Please help me to run the Application